# What is the name of a some hardware-device feature which displays user's internet connections?

Tags: networking, router, firewall, modem

### Problem:

I'm trying to find a small hardware device (eg. a modem/router? firewall?) that can tell me who (private LAN IP addresses) is connecting to what other (public) IP's and their up/down speeds**.

#### Context:

At our small office (around 20 odd staff, depending on who's in/wtf/flown in) sometimes our internet traffic slows down due to lots of internet usage == our download and/or upload pipe getting saturated.

I would like to see which devices are connecting to where and are downloading what. NOW BEFORE PEOPLE GET ANGRY HERE ... I *do not* want to see the *actual* content or file names, etc .. just that Ip addy `192.168.0.69` is consuming 52 k/s from mozilla.org (eg. downloading firefox) etc..

for example:

- `192.168.0 69` : mozilla.org : down 52 k/s
- `192.168.0.51` : youtube.com : down 101 k/s
- `192.168.0.100` : docs.google.com : up 12 k/s

so this means I can at least go over to the device which could be consuming a lot of bandwidth and fix the problem (or ask them to stop for a wee bit).

Now .. the *main* reason for this is not to be mean, but .. lots of users don't know that they have the entire flickr photo gallery silently sync'ing or that their dropbox is quietly syncing, etc.

Secondly, please do not:

- Suggest I get a fatter pipe / better download plan/speeds
- Firewall / block all places and enforce group policies, etc
- lock down all computers and only install what is *approved*, etc.
- Grab a computer and install linux and then blah blah blah linux-pro-stuff-etc
- Buy an R-PI and install linux or whatever is the current flavour, etc.

Just don't go there suggesting that, please.

But I am happy to flash a hardware device though :)

Anyone have any clues to tell me what devices I should be looking for .. or what features on a device .. which does this type of thing?

Comment: Relevant: [Network Traffic Monitoring](http://serverfault.com/q/3326)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any SNMP-enabled (or having some sort of counters in it's management interface) switch to see the bandwidth usage on each port, but it will not tell you what your users actually doing, it will even can't tell local traffic apart from internet. And if there's more than 1 machine on a single port, you will not find which one is consuming the bandwidth.

Also having a switch that can mirror all traffic to some dedicated port will allow you to use some sniffing software to see who goes where. For example, EtherApe can draw a connection graph that will help you to get a quick look on what's going on.

On the other side, you can use a router that can show all connections in it's management interface. It's mostly a software feature, not hardware. I've seen something similar in MikroTik and newer ZyXEL devices. But when you have a lot of connections, there'll be a real mess.

Comment: What is this software feature called ... which some hardware device will offer? is there some common name for this feature? Also, SNMP can't help -> i need an IP report, not an ethernet or NIC report.

Comment: In ZyXEL, it's just a tab called "Connections". MikroTik's RouterOS is very feature-rich and provides a lot of tools to analyze the traffic. The same list can be found here under "Packet Sniffer".